# Windows Mobile hardware buttons

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-10-mobile

I am new to windows mobile development. how can I access the hardware keys like volume down,volume up, power button by programmatic in c#.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 8.1 you have a class **HardwareButtons** which contains 4 events:

1. BackPressed
2. CameraHalfPressed
3. CameraPressed
4. CameraReleased

If you want use this in WIndows 10, you need add extension library

[image]

and get API for Windows Phone 8.1

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known if you are an OEM, then the OEM has the special permissions to access these hardware button like the volume/power button, for more information, please try to refer to this article.
But if you are an ordinary developers, I think it is not possible to access these hardware button like the volume/power button, in my mind these volume/power hardware button should be accessed/controled by the user not by the app.